# Adding custom color bar on top of ionic icon in ionic list

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to add a color bar (red color bar in image) on top of the ionic icon as shown in the following image. I am using ionic list .

I have tried using div before the icon but I didn't achieve this.
I am using **ionic framework** with **angularjs** for hybrid app development.
If anyone could help.I will be thankful.

[image]

I tried doing this by using

```
 <a class="item item-icon-left item-icon-right" style="text-align: left;border-top-left-radius: 10px;border-top-right-radius: 10px;
                            border-color: #abadad;
                            ">
 <div style="width: 15px;height:3px; background-color: red;float:left;margin-left:0; "></div>
 <i class="icon ion-clipboard" style="color: #5e5e5e;"></i>

 <h2 style="font-weight: bold;">Bill No:25</h2>
 <i class="icon  ion-card" style="color: #5e5e5e;"></i>
 </a>
```

But I can achieve this

[image]